# Android change bitmap src inside the application

Tags: android, bitmap, background-image

I've got an application and I would like to change the bitmap source inside the code.
I have got the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="5px"
   android:paddingRight="5px"
   android:paddingTop="5px"
   android:background="@drawable/my_image"
>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the xml for the background:

```
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:dither="true"
android:gravity="bottom|right"
android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

Now, when there is an image name inside the source then it works, but I would like the change it when I select another list item in the previous class. I know there is getResources, but I don't really know how to solve it with bitmap. When there is string then it's easy, but in this way I don't know where to go.

Answer (score 0):

Put the xml of the bitmap in drawable folder and then set the background resource as android:background="@drawable/bitmap" (bitmap is the name of that xml in drawable).
or give an id to the relative layout and use Relativelayout.setBackgroundResource() method.